# Method parameter casted to my type but its property is not recognized

Tags: typescript, xstate

I am using XState and I need to pass a parameter via an Event.

```
export type InitializationEvent =
  | { type: 'FETCHED', name: string }
  | { type: 'ERROR', name: string }
  | { type: 'RESTART', name: string }
```

This is a method where I want to use the name property:

```
someAction: (context, event: InitializationEvent) => {
   doSomething(event.name);
},
```

Idea shows the event type is:

```
Alias for: InitEvent | {type: 'FETCHED', name: string} | {type: 'ERROR', name: string} | {type: 'RESTART', name: string}
```

`InitEvent` comes from the XState as:

```
export declare type InitEvent = { type: 'xstate.init'; }
```

But the build fails with:

```
TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'InitializationEvent'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'InitEvent'.
```

How can I properly access it? The method parameter `event` is cast to `InitializationEvent` so it should work, no?

Comment: What is `InitEvent`?

Comment: Some type  coming from XState: export declare type InitEvent = {
    type: 'xstate.init';
}

Comment: please put your .TS filenames and your TSConfig.json in the opening as well.

Comment: Remark:  this type of errors can happen with import/export errors in TypeScript. It sees the class name, but it does not see its properties.

Comment: It compiles when I enclose the property access in if (event.type !== 'xstate.init') {}.

Comment: What if you change doSomething(event.name) to doSomething(event.type)  ? just to test it ? does that compile properly ?

Comment: Yes, type attribute is accessible.